# Getting an XML element inside XSLT

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I want to find the value of an XML element inside XSL. My JS selects one XML document, but there are elements in others that I need to get.

I am not sure if this is possible or if my syntax is wrong.

This is what I have.

```
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="document(newXMLfile.xml)/Customers/customer/type" />
</td>
```

the XML of the new file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <Customers> 
      <customer> 
          <Order>12000</Order>
          <ID>200</ID> 
          <Date>1 Sep 2010</Date> 
          <type>true</type> 
      </customer>
 </Customers>
```

Comment: You're using Javascript to call an XSLT to read another XML file?

Comment: My JS calls the first XML file and the XSL file in question. I wish to call yet another XML file within the XSL. I am looping through to make a new row for ever entry. I am guessing I am doing it wrong but I can't figure out how I would do it with a global variable in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes:

```
<xsl:value-of select="document('newXMLfile.xml')/Customers/customer/type" />
```

Comment: Thank you. I am guessing that is an improvement because now the whole table doesn't load. Before, the cell was just empty. So I think it is now recognizing the document but I think my XPath expression is wrong?

Comment: @TomNagle, Could you provide `newXMLfile.xml` because provided XML isn't well-formed.

Comment: I added it to my original post. This is only a fragment of the file. But the rest is the same stuff, just different element values.

Comment: I'm completely stumped on how to tackle this one. Thank you for your help anyway

Answer (score 0):

A good debugging technique with calls on document() is to use the call

```
<div id="debug">
  <xsl:copy-of select="document('newXMLfile.xml')"/>
</div>
```

to copy the document directly to the output. This will help you determine whether the problem is in reading the document, or in selecting nodes within it.

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** Be sure to be seeing and mentioning any error messages in the logs/console.  This is particularly important if you're not running the XSLT processor from a command line directly.  (You mention running it from within JavaScript.)

**(2)** Make sure your XML side document file is being read.  You might change the filename given to `document()` to be something you're sure does not exist (e.g. `document('XXX_newXMLfile.xml')`) to verify that you're seeing an appropriate error message when the file is not being specified correctly.  If you must specify a path to a local file, use this notation:

```
'file:///path/newXMLfile.xml'
```

Yes, that's three slashes after `file:`.  On Windows, `path` will typically include a drive designation such as `c:`.